# How to unzip a local file using a gulp task

Tags: node.js, npm, unzip, gulp

I'm looking for a way to extract a JAR file (zip) using a gulp task but can't wrap my head around connecting a stream and the unzip.Extract().

Here's the Gulp task I've currently got.  It doesn't error out and doesn't actually extract my JAR.

```
gulp.task('unzip-jar', function(){
    return gulp.src("myjar.jar")
        .pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: './output' }));

});
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Forgot to mention the unzip plugin I am using is https://www.npmjs.org/package/unzip, with the import of:

```
    unzip = require('unzip'),
```

This probably isn't necessary but I can't figure out the "correct" way to do this.

Comment: Where are you getting `unzip` from?  I don't see any unzip gulp plugins, and you can't just blindly pass a function into a pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's no need for a gulp plugin. Just include this in the middle of the pipeline:

```
.pipe(zlib.createUnzip());
```

And this at the top:

```
var zlib = require("zlib");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I removed the "unzip" plugin and tried to place that between a normal gulp pipeline with no luck.  I used something like this (and all sorts of other variations):

    gulp.src("myzip.zip")
            .pipe(zlib.createUnzip())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(app.dist));